# can i set logstash default elasticsearch mapping through elasticsearch-template.json

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I use logstash + elasticsearch to collect syslog and want to set ttl for log ageing

I find a file named elasticsearch-template.json in the logstash,the path is logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json

I add ttl info in the file like this:

```
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
       "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
       "dynamic_templates" : [ {
         "string_fields" : {
           "match" : "*",
           "match_mapping_type" : "string",
           "mapping" : {
             "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
               "fields" : {
                 "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
               }
           }
         }
       } ],
        "_ttl": {
         "enabled": true,
         "default": "1d"
       },
       "properties" : {
         "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
         "geoip"  : {
           "type" : "object",
             "dynamic": true,
             "path": "full",
             "properties" : {
               "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
             }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

then restart logstash, delete all elasticsearch index. 
I check the new index's mapping in the elasticsearch, but it didn't work in this way.

How can I config the index template?

Comment: For new visitors, there is a plugin named "kopf" with lots of features. One of them is to edit template easily and save it in an editor. Things like changing the number of shards/replica based on your cluster etc.

Answer (score 8):

you need to change your logstash configuration.

if you have followed the default settings, logstash has already created a template inside elasticsearch named `logstash`, logstash will keep on using that template stored in elasticsearch unless you tell it not to explicitly.

modify that template file you found but in addition to that, in your logstash configuration, set the following:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    template_overwrite => true
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I access the logstash template file? where is it located?

Comment: It should be in your logstash directory, if you fail to find it you could always create your own and ask logstash to use the customized template file in logstash's configuration file. Add `template => "/path/to/elasticsearch_template.json" \n template_name =>"the_name_you_want"` in your logstash configuration. I have examples here: https://github.com/xialingxiao/andokaelk/blob/master/roles/logstash/templates/logstash_connector.conf for logstash configuration and https://github.com/xialingxiao/andokaelk/blob/master/roles/logstash/templates/elasticsearch_template.json for elasticsearch_template.

Comment: Note that the `template` field in `elasticsearch_template.json` has to be compatible with the elasticsearch `index` name logstash is writing to configured in `logstash.conf`.

Comment: What if I want to make changes to this file? Do I need to change at multiple places? It is located at `/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.5.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json` in my system. Now, if I want to set message to not analyzed, it is not working. It is still analyzed.

Comment: If you have done everything I mentioned and it didn't work, it is mostly because you did not reindex your data. I don't think you can change your schema for the index if the index is existing already. You need to reindex everything to a new index or delete the current index and re-import your data

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like that JSON file is in the correct folder. Here is the documentation on how to use the templates:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html
About the folder:

Config

Index templates can also be placed within the config location (path.conf) under the templates directory (note, make sure to place them on all master eligible nodes). For example, a file called template_1.json can be placed under config/templates and it will be added if it matches an index. Here is a sample of the mentioned file:

Comment: thank you for your answer. I find the config(path.conf) in "/elasticsearch-1.4.0/config/elasticsearch.yml",but how to set the index template use this way? I'm sorry I don't see your sample file.

Comment: Just create the template folder inside your config folder and copy the JSON file over. Then just restart ES and you should have the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I've created new template.json file and defined path to it into elasticsearch output block of logstash.yml config file:

```
stdout { codec => json_lines }

elasticsearch {

"hosts" => ["ip:port"]
"index" => "name-of-index-%{+dd.MM.YYYY}"
template => "/{path-to-logstash-folder}/templates/your-template.json"
template_overwrite => true
manage_template => false
}
```

document_type for Elastic I defined into input block of logstash.yml config file:

```
input {

file {
path => "/your-path-to-directory/*.log"
type => "name-of-type"
 }
}
```

There is my template.json file

```
{
"name-of-index": {
"order": 0,
"version": 50001,
"template": "name-of-index-*",
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "refresh_interval": "5s"
  }
},
"mappings": {
  "_default_": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "message_field": {
          "path_match": "message",
          "mapping": {
            "norms": false,
            "type": "text"
          },
          "match_mapping_type": "string"
        }
      },
      {
        "string_fields": {
          "mapping": {
            "norms": false,
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "match": "*"
        }
      }
    ],
    "_all": {
      "norms": false,
      "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "include_in_all": false,
        "type": "date"
      },
      "geoip": {
        "dynamic": true,
        "properties": {
          "ip": {
            "type": "ip"
          },
          "latitude": {
            "type": "half_float"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "longitude": {
            "type": "half_float"
          }
        }
      },
      "@version": {
        "include_in_all": false,
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
},
"aliases": {}
 }
 }
```