# How to map geoip field in logstash with elasticsearch in order to display it in tile map of Kibana4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'd like to display geoip fields in tile map of Kibana4. 
Using the standard / automatic logstash geoip mapping to elasticsearch it all works fine.

However when creating a non-standard geoip field, I am not quite sure how to customize the elasticsearch-template.json in logstash in order to represent this field correctly in elasticsearch so that it can be chosen in Kibana4 for tile map creation.

Sure, customizing the standard template is not the best way - better create a custom template and point to it in elasticsearch output of logstash.conf. I just quickly wanted to check how the mapping has to be defined, so I modified the standard template.

My logstash.conf:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 514
        type => syslog
    }
    udp {
        port => 514
        type => syslog
    }
}

filter {
    # Standard geoip field is automatically mapped by logstash to 
    # elastic search by using the elasticsearch-template.json file
    geoip { source => "host" }

    grok {
        match => [ 
            "message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{YEAR} %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{DATA:device} <%{POSINT:status}> %{WORD:activity} %{DATA:inout} \(%{DATA:msg}\) Src:%{IPV4:src} SPort:%{INT:sport} Dst:%{IPV4:dst} DPort:%{INT:dport} IPP:%{INT:ipp} Rule:%{INT:rule} Interface:%{WORD:iface}",
            "message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{YEAR} %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{DATA:device} <%{POSINT:status}> %{WORD:activity} %{DATA:inout} \(%{DATA:msg}\) Src:%{IPV4:src} Dst:%{IPV4:dst} IPP:%{INT:ipp} Rule:%{INT:rule} Interface:%{WORD:iface}",                    
            "message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{YEAR} %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{DATA:device} <%{POSINT:status}> %{WORD:activity} %{DATA:inout} \(%{DATA:msg}\) Src:%{IPV4:src} Dst:%{IPV4:dst} Type:%{POSINT:type} Code:%{INT:code} IPP:%{INT:ipp} Rule:%{INT:rule} Interface:%{WORD:iface}"
        ]
    }
    # Is not mapped automatically by logstash in that it can be 
    # chosen in Kibana4 for tile map creation
    geoip {
        source => "src"
        target => "src_geoip"
    }   
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        protocol => "http"
    }
}
```

My ...logstash-1.4.2\lib\logstash\outputs\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-template.json:

```
    {
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
       "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
       "dynamic_templates" : [ {
         "string_fields" : {
           "match" : "*",
           "match_mapping_type" : "string",
           "mapping" : {
             "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
               "fields" : {
                 "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
               }
           }
         }
       } ],
       "properties" : {
         "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
         "geoip"  : {
           "type" : "object",
             "dynamic": true,
             "path": "full",
             "properties" : {
               "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
             }
         },
         "src_geoip"  : {
           "type" : "object",
             "dynamic": true,
             "path": "full",
             "properties" : {
               "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
             }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I havent figured out yet when this json file gets applied in elasticsearch. I followed the hints outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524252/can-i-set-logstash-default-elasticsearch-mapping-through-elasticsearch-template) and copied the json file to a config/templates folder in elasticsearch directory. After deleting the indizes and restart of elasticsearch, the template was applied successfully.

Anyway, the field "src_geoip.location" still does not show up in the tile map creation form of Kibana4 (only the standard geoip.location field does).

Comment: Have you created a new index after applying the new index template? Have you tried using the [get mapping API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) to obtain the actual mapping of the index in question?

Comment: Yes, I stopped EL and deleted the index directory. Is this sufficient for deleting an index or do I have to perfom this via REST?  I use the chrome extension "sense" to send REST messages to EL the command GET /_mapping/ shows all mappings. The standard geoip seems fine ... dynamic = true, location = geopoint. But src_geoip is different: No dynamic = true and location = double. Seems my mapping is wrong or is not applied.

Comment: When I create a template dir in config dir of EL and move the json file to that direction it works after the deletion of the index and restart of EL. So now, the correct mapping is present. However, I'm not able to chose the corresponding field in the creation form of tile map at KB4

Answer (score 1):

Try overwrite template after editing template. Re-create indexes in Kibana after config change.

```
output {
   elasticsearch {
       template_overwrite => "true"
        ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add objects for the src_geoip object in the index template on your elasticsearch instance. To set the default template for all indexes that match "logstash-netflow-*", execute the following on your elasticsearch instance:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/logstash-netflow -d '{
"template" : "logstash-netflow-*",
"mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
    "_all" : {
      "enabled" : false
    },
    "properties" : {
      "@timestamp" : { "index" : "analyzed", "type" : "date" },
      "@version" : { "index" : "analyzed", "type" : "integer" },
      "src_geoip" : {
        "dynamic" : true,
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "area_code" : { "type" : "long" },
          "city_name" : { "type" : "string" }, 
          "continent_code" : { "type" : "string" }, 
          "country_code2" : { "type" : "string" },
          "country_code3" : { "type" : "string" },
          "country_name" : { "type" : "string" },
          "dma_code" : { "type" : "long" },
          "ip" : { "type" : "string" },
          "latitude" : { "type" : "double" },
          "location" : { "type" : "double" },
          "longitude" : { "type" : "double" },
          "postal_code" : { "type" : "string" },
          "real_region_name" : { "type" : "string" },
          "region_name" : { "type" : "string" },
          "timezone" : { "type" : "string" }
        }
      },
      "netflow" : { ....snipped......
      }
    }
  }
}}'
```